# KeystoneJS CSRF on own pages

Tags: node.js, csrf, keystonejs

I'm searching for an easy way to set an CSRF Token and check it on every POST/PUT/... request.

There is already an mechanism in the AdminUI. Can this be used on the "normal" webpages?

I'm aware of the `keystone.security.csrf.middleware.init` and `keystone.security.csrf.middleware.validate` functions. But where is the best place to call them?

Many thanks in advance!
Daniel

Edit:
I have tried to use

`keystone.pre('routes', keystone.security.csrf.middleware.init);`
`keystone.pre('routes', keystone.security.csrf.middleware.validate);`

in my routes file. The token is set in my cookie. Also the cookie is transmitted when I request the server.
But the validate method tells me: "mismatch token". Maybe I have an conceptual misunderstanding. I thought, that this would work out of the box. What am I missing?

Edit2:
I will add the token to my form. I missed this step...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call it as a common middleware, just define it in your routes/index.js file:

```
keystone.pre('routes', keystone.security.csrf.middleware.init);
```

Comment: That is a nice keystonejs-way. Is there any documentation for the Keystone pre and set methods? I want to know where the best place for the validate method is.

Comment: It would be nice if you could take a look at my edited question. Maybe you have a hint for me? If not, no problem. You basically pointed me in the right direction and I will accept your answer soon.

Comment: When you make a POST request, in case you're trying to log-in, you need to pass an email, password and _csrf parameter